# Android: set view height via ViewTreeObserver

Tags: android, android-view

I have two tables: TableA and TableB. TableA has the first row with height of 22 and TableB has the first row with height of 77. I want to equate first row of TableA to first row of TableB, for that purpose I use code below:

```
void resizeHeaderHeight() {
    final int[] heightA = new int[1];
    final int[] heightB = new int[1];

    TableRow TableA_Row = (TableRow) this.tableA.getChildAt(0);
    TableRow TableB_Row = (TableRow) this.tableB.getChildAt(0);

    final TextView textViewA = (TextView) TableA_Row.getChildAt(0);
    final TextView textViewB = (TextView) TableB_Row.getChildAt(0);


    ViewTreeObserver vto = textViewB.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            textViewA.getViewTreeObserver();
            textViewB.getViewTreeObserver();
            heightA[0] = textViewA.getMeasuredHeight();
            heightB[0] = textViewB.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.d(TAG, "TableA_Row height = " + heightA[0]);
            Log.d(TAG, "TableB_Row height = " + heightB[0]);

            textViewA.setHeight(heightB[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

But I doubt whether this is the right approach or not ?

Because when I look in logcat, it always prints me my Logs, but if I remove `textViewA.setHeight(heightB[0]);` it prints Logs just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming your layout is correctly designed and this way of setting height of your `textViewB` is the one you really wanna go with...*

You should remove `OnGlobalLayoutListener` as soon as it's not needed anymore. You're not doing that, and the `onGlobalLayout` callback is getting called on any change in the `ViewTree` layout. So answering your question: the way you're using `ViewTreeObserver` is not the best...

This way would be better:

```
void resizeHeaderHeight() {
    TableRow TableA_Row = (TableRow) this.tableA.getChildAt(0);
    TableRow TableB_Row = (TableRow) this.tableB.getChildAt(0);

    final TextView textViewA = (TextView) TableA_Row.getChildAt(0);
    final TextView textViewB = (TextView) TableB_Row.getChildAt(0);

    textViewB.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int heightB = textViewB.getHeight();
            if (heightB > 0) {
                // removing OnGlobalLayoutListener
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    textViewB.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    textViewB.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

                // setting height
                textViewA.setHeight(heightB);
            }
        }
    });
}
```