# Update View's dimensions after adding children

Tags: java, android, view, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with a `ConstraintLayout` (and a few other things) which I'm populating programatically with children. I'm having hard time resizing the parent `RelativeLayout` after initializing all child views.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this:

[quick mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpTvP.png)

Here are code snippets:

```
@BindView(R.id.session_summary_items_include_correct) View mCardCorrect;

//...

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_session_summary_items, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    correctCard = new IncludedCard();
    ButterKnife.bind(correctCard, mCardCorrect);

    initializeViews();

    mCardCorrect.post(() -> resizeView(mCardCorrect));

    return view;
}

private void initializeViews(){
    ArrayList<MyClass> items = MyClass.GetItems();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     

    if (items.size() > 0){
        correctCard.mCardTitle.setText("Correct Card");
        ArrayList<View> views = getItemViews(items, layoutInflater);
        populateLayoutWithItemViews(correctCard.mConstraintLayout, views);
    }
}  

private ArrayList<View> getItemViews(ArrayList<MyClass> items, LayoutInflater inflater){
    ArrayList<View> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MyClass item : items){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
        TextView mTextTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_view_title);
        mTextTitle .setText(item.getTitle());
        results.add(view);
    }
    return results;
}

 private void populateLayoutWithItemViews(ConstraintLayout layout, ArrayList<View> items){

    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(layout);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < items.size(); idx ++){
        View item = items.get(idx);
        item.setId(View.generateViewId());
        layout.addView(item);

        // constraintSet magic to make them connect as expected

    }

    constraintSet.applyTo(layout);
}

private void resizeView(View view){

    view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}

static class IncludedCard{
    @BindView(R.id.card_title) TextView mCardTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.card_layout) ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout;
}
```

Now, the issue is that wherever, whenever and however I'll measure / resize the mCardCorrect View, the result is the same: it'll be measured up to card title, as if the children items inside ConstraintLayout were not there. Like this:

[measurement bounding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NKqt.png)

I've tried posting measurements / resizing to a Runnable like here: [FrameLayout child view not updating correctly on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041691/framelayout-child-view-not-updating-correctly-on-resize)
, and using OnGlobalLayoutListener like here: [Android: set view height via ViewTreeObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818093/android-set-view-height-via-viewtreeobserver)
. I'm still an Android newb and this is my first project, so any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain each view. From ["Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout"](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constraints-overview):

> ... if a view has no constraints when you run your layout on a device, it is drawn at position [0,0] (the top-left corner).

All of the views you add are not constrained, so they all overlap each other at (0, 0).

It looks like you setting up the `ConstraintSet` correctly, you will just need to add the constraints using the `ConstraintSet`. There are some good tutorial online that demonstrate how to do this. [Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_ConstraintSet_Tutorial#Configuring_the_Constraint_Set) is one. You can also refer to the [official documenation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html).